# Error when using "get_the_category" in Wordpress functions file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to display the posts for the first category of the post where the shortcode is used and I'm doing this through the functions.php file (or custom plugin). The code works as intended but when I use the shortcode on a post and try to save it, it gives the following error:

*Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.*

Code:

```
function wpb_postsbycategory() {
    $category = get_the_category();
    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => $firstCategory, 
        'posts_per_page' => 10 
    ) ); 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $string .= '<h2>Posts for Category: ' . $firstCategory . '</h2><ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'"><span>' . get_the_title() .'</span></a></li>';
        }
    } else {
     $string .= '<li>No Posts Found</li>';
    }
    $string .= '</ul>';
    return $string;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I tested your exact code and it works as intended. Have you tried switching to a default theme to see if it's something in your theme?

Comment: You should also check your server error logs. They may contain an Fatal PHP error, that the admin area isn't showing you.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata();` won't execute, when you place it _after_ a `return` statement.

Comment: @disinfor You are correct, it's working well. it was a conflict with another plugin. Thanks for the feedback.